# Can't connect to SQL Server on Virtualbox

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, virtualbox

This may be simple to solve, but I'm clueless...

I have SQL Server 2012 on my laptop with Windows 8 and Virtualbox with Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012, and I want to test Transactional Replication by using the host machine as the publisher/distributor and the VM as the subscriber. Thing is, I can't seem to connect the host to the guest -- I can't access the guest database from inside the host database, but I do seem to be able to connect the guest to the host. SQL Configuration Manager seems right, I tried using the VM with both NAT and bridge, and I have internet connection on the VM.

If I type the IP address of the VM on the host's SQL Server and the sa user (actually, any user), I get the message saying 'sa' login failed. I can't connect with the guest's domain name.

Also, when I start the jobs at the host, a message appears on the log saying that there are no replications available or something.

I was following this tutorial: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337437.aspx

Comment: 1. Can you use Management Studio on the **guest** to connect to the guest SQL Server using the sa user? 2. Can you use Management Studio on the **host** to connect to the guest SQL Server using the sa user? 3. Do the error logs on the guest SQL Server show anything?

Comment: I can connect the guest to the host using the sa user, but not the other way around.

Comment: Can you use Management Studio on the **guest** to connect to the **guest** SQL Server using the sa user? That is, does sa work at all on the guest host?